# PHP Include. I can't figure out why I can't run my functions

Tags: php, laravel

Ok so I have been reading the PHP Docs trying to figure out what isn't working here. So I'm using Laravel and in my master file in my header I am including my functions file located in public/includes. I have used a simple php code instead of blade functions for this.

public.blade.php

```
<?php include 'includes/nashFunctions.php'; ?>
```

I am positive I'm extending the master file where I am trying to call my data. I've got a function in there, but I wanted to test it with a simple variable by putting

```
<?php $hello = 'hello world'; ?>
```

in the nashFunctions.php. Now when I go into my file and try and call the variable:

```
<?php echo $hello; ?>
```

I get this error message:

> Undefined variable: hello (View:/resources/views/teams.blade.php)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: in your nashFunctions.php file have you tried putting an echo as your first line. for example echo "the file is included"; If the include was successful the output should appear.

Comment: @SheppardDigital I just tried that and sure enough at the top of the page "the file is included" appeared. Why can't I use my functions and variables from the file?

Answer (score 0):

So I found help elsewhere, but I wanted to put my answer in case anyone else came across it. Here is the help I was given by /u/11ry on reddit:

> Instead of doing it the way you've described, create a file in the app folder and call it helpers.php or functions.php or whatever. Then, goto your composer.json file and add this . Don't forget to run a "composer update" when done.

[image]

Comment: update _also_ does dumpautoload, but I still agree because update can have unintended side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Your `nashFunctions.php` located in `public\includes` folder and your `teams.blade.php` is located in `view` folder. If you want to use `Raw PHP Code` you have to write the full path of the file location.

Change `<?php include 'includes/nashFunctions.php'; ?>` to `<?php include '../../public/includes/nashFunctions.php' ?>`

Hope it will work.